# Magento Shopping cart price rule category chooser not working for custom role

Tags: magento, roles, rules

Magento ver 1.9.1.1

I have a custom role set up for site maintenance. This custom role has a custom resource list in which the Promotions -> shopping cart price rules is ticked.

The role can successfully access this area but when you click in the little Chooser icon when creating conditions it shows the magento loading icon then redirects the user to System->My Account.

[image]

I have made no changes to the core of Magento regarding any of this functionality.

Does anybody have any idea what might cause this, or has anyone experienced this?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a minor bug at magento.
Internal modules are not separate. It connect with all of Promotion rules.

If you want to assign to someone a promotion role, you also have to select Catalog Price Rules at the role resources.

Then it can be worked normally.

[image]

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the response, it sounds promising, I will try applying it tonight when I get home and report back / accept the answer.